# How to use Windows default dir like %OneDrive% in browser address bar to access folder?

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge, filepath

When using Windows File Explorer, one can type `%OneDrive%` in the address bar to access the OneDrive Folder.When using Internet Explorer, one can also type `file:///%OneDrive%` to access the Onedrive Folder.

But for new Microsoft Edge, url like `file:///%OneDrive%` will only get the error message "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND".

**So is there any solutions to access the default OneDrive folder without using the absolute path in Microsoft Edge?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security purposes, you cannot access the one drive folder located on the machine using the file:// protocol in the MS Edge browser.

It is not recommended and considered as a bad practice to access the local folder/ files using the File:// protocol in the browser. Most of the latest browsers including the MS Edge would not allow users to access the files like this.

I suggest you use File Explorer to access the OneDrive folder.

If you are available with the IIS then as a workaround, you could try to create a virtual directory in IIS for your OneDrive folder. It will use the HTTP or HTTPS protocols and you will be able to access the folder using the Edge browser.